# possible to tween d3.geo.circle().angle()

Tags: d3.js, geo, tween

I'm trying to recreate the "pulse" effect from this example:

```
https://anthonyskelton.com/2016/d3-js-earthquake-visualizations/
```

on a rotating globe... so I have to use d3.geo.circle() to generate paths (rather than svg circles) to manage the clipping properly.

I can transition() other attributes but am guessing I'll need to tween the path for each circle... I just don't know where to start and can't find any examples... there are very few examples using d3.geo.circle() and they are all static.

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: What version of d3 and what have tried so far?

Comment: Hi Kevin ~ I'm using D3v3 but will probably move the whole thing to v4. I'll try to extract an example from the larger project... I just wanted to know if its even possible, because I can't find any examples that are remotely similar.

Comment: Are you trying to place an arc, and then a circle on the map when the arc 'lands'?

Comment: no, trying to recreate the 'pulse' from the url mentioned above. an existing circle would get a larger radius and then transition back to its original size. Simple with normal circles, but I'm trying to use geo.circle() so that it works on a rotating globe.

Comment: I finally found an example that should work: http://jsfiddle.net/Lg9z57g5/

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this question came by way of pursuing a related question: 
[D3: Accessing bound data after using .datum()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40225671/d3-accessing-bound-data-after-using-datum/40236256#40236256)

The first step was understanding ***d3.geo.path().pointRadius()*** and creating a function to pass into ***.attr('d', f(d){})***

The parameter ***i*** is unused but serves as a placeholder so that the radius ***r*** can be passed.

The ***pointPath()*** function is used elsewhere in ***update()*** and ***reDraw()*** functions, so it looks for a radius attribute that may already be present in bound data.

```
  geoPath = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

  // var pointPath = function(d, i, data, r) { // d3v4 adds extra param
  var pointPath = function(d, i, r) {
     if (d.properties && d.properties.radius != undefined) {
        r = r || d.properties.radius;
     }
     r = r || 1.5;
     var coords = [d.geometry.coordinates[0], d.geometry.coordinates[1]];
     var pr = geoPath.pointRadius(globe.scale() / 100 * r);
     return pr({ type: "Point", coordinates: coords })
  }
```

The animation was then possible using an ***.attrTween()***

```
  pulse = function() {
     surface.selectAll('.pulse-circle')
        .attr("d", function(d) { return pointPath(d, 0, 0); })
        .style("fill-opacity", 1 )
        .transition()
        .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 200; })
        .duration(3000)
        .style("fill-opacity", 0 )
        .attrTween("d", function(d) {
          rinterp = d3.interpolate(0, 10);
          var fn = function(t) {
            d.r = rinterp(t);
            return pointPath(d, 0, d.r) || 'M0,0';
          };
          return fn;
        });
  }
```

Because this occurs on a rotating globe I had to add return ***'M0,0'*** if ***pointPath()*** returned undefined... to avoid console errors.

Comment: My solution in context can be found in the "Reusable Updateable Global Mashup" blocks here: http://bl.ocks.org/TennisVisuals